# Working out certain values from a nested dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

Say I had a nested dictionary:

```
      myDict = { 'a': { 1: 2,
                        2: 163,
                        3: 12,
                        4: 67,
                        5: 84
                        },
             'about': { 1: 27,
                        2: 45,
                        3: 21,
                        4: 10,
                        5: 15
                        },
                'an': { 1:  3,
                        2: 15,
                        3:  1,
                        4:312,
                        5:100
                        }
        'anticipate': { 1:  1,
                        2:  5,
                        3:  0,
                        4:  8,
                        5:  7
                        }
             'apple': { 1:  0,
                        2:  5,
                        3:  0,
                        4:  10,
                        5:  0
                        }
           }
```

The outer key is a word, the inner keys are the files that that word contains and the values are the number of times said word appears in that file.

I want to work out 2 things:

The first is the number of times each word appears in total so for 'a' it would be 328.

The second is the number of files containing each word so it would be 5 for 'a' but 2 for 'apple'.

I'm guessing these 'values' will be two dictionaries but standard ones rather than nested i.e. {word : total count} and {word : num of files it appears in}.

Edit: Another thing I'd like to work out is each file's word vector magnitude.

So for file 1 it would be sqrt (2^2 + 27^2 + 3^2 + 1^2 + 0^2)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IIUC, you can do this straightforwardly with dictionary comprehensions.

Total of all the values in a given word's dictionary:

```
>>> {k: sum(d.values()) for k,d in myDict.items()}
{'a': 328, 'about': 118, 'apple': 15, 'anticipate': 21, 'an': 431}
```

Number of values in the subdictionary which are greater than zero:

```
>>> {k: sum(v > 0 for v in d.values()) for k,d in myDict.items()}
{'a': 5, 'about': 5, 'apple': 2, 'anticipate': 4, 'an': 5}
```

This last one relies upon the fact that `int(True) == 1` and `int(False) == 0`, so we don't need to write `1 if v > 0 else 0` or something, but can sum the booleans instead.

Comment: Sorry I have one more thing I'd like to work out but it's more complicated than the other 2?

Comment: I'll add it into the original description.

Comment: It's better to ask separate questions where possible.  SO doesn't work like a threaded forum, but in a question/answer setup.

Comment: I asked a separate question and just got burned for it!

Answer (score 0):

Okay, your problems aren't very difficult.

Problem 1: "The first is the number of times each word appears in total so for 'a' it would be 328."

```
word = "a"
total = sum(myDict[word].values())
print total
```

Or, if you want to calculate it for every key in myDict:

```
for word in myDict:
    total = sum(myDict[word].values())
    print word, total
```

Problem 2: "The second is the number of files containing each word so it would be 5 for 'a' but 2 for 'apple'."

```
for word in myDict:
    number_of_files = sum(bool(v) for v in myDict[word].values())
    print word, number_of_files
```

Answer (score 0):

The nested dictionary is a VERY VERY bad data structure for a term-document matrix. Instead use a numpy array as suggested in [Calculating distance between word/document vectors from a nested dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27027680/calculating-distance-between-word-document-vectors-from-a-nested-dictionary)

Even if you don't fancy the use of numpy array, there is no need for a dictionary of dictionaries structure since **your inner keys are sequential**. You could have use the following structure which will simplify how you should store your data:

```
myDict = {'a':[2, 163, 12, 67, 84], 
          'about':[27, 45, 21, 10, 15], 
          'apple':[0, 5, 0, 10, 0], 
          'anticipate': [1, 5, 0, 8, 7], 
          'an':[3, 15, 1, 312, 100]}
```

And when you access you use the same method but start from 0th indexing in the inner key:

```
print myDict['a'][0] # a in 1st document
print myDict['a'][1] # a in 2nd document
print myDict['apple'][2] # apple in 3rd document
```

To calculate the sum for each word simply:

```
sum(myDict['a'])
sum([1 for word in myDict if myDict[word] > 0])
```

Here's the full code:

```
myDict = {'a': {1:2, 2:163, 3:12, 4:67, 5:84}, 
          'about': {1:27, 2:45, 3:21, 4:10, 5:15}, 
          'apple': {1:0, 2: 5, 3:0, 4:10, 5:0}, 
          'anticipate': {1:1, 2:5, 3:0, 4:8, 5:7}, 
          'an': {1:3, 2:15, 3:1, 4:312, 5:100}}

myDict = {'a':[2, 163, 12, 67, 84], 
          'about':[27, 45, 21, 10, 15], 
          'apple':[0, 5, 0, 10, 0], 
          'anticipate': [1, 5, 0, 8, 7], 
          'an':[3, 15, 1, 312, 100]}

print myDict['a'][0] # a in 1st document
print myDict['a'][1] # a in 2nd document
print myDict['apple'][2] # apple in 3rd document 

print sum(myDict['a'])
# How many documents does apple occur in?
print sum([1 for doc in myDict['apple'] if doc > 0])
```

Once again, I stress that **using dictionary of dictionary where the inner keys are sequential integers is senseless**, you can simply strip the inner keys.